# Chrome (WebKit) ng-model issues with select display value

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome, webkit

I'm thinking that I'm experiencing this bug:

[Github -> AngularJS -> #7986](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7986)

Here's my code:

```
<select ng-model="storeaccount" ng-init="storeaccount = store != 0 ? store : null" ng-options="storedata.id as storedata.name for storedata in stores" ng-change="storeAccountChange(storeaccount)">
    <option value="">-- Choose store account --</option>
</select>
```

Anyone got any clues to how I've might solve this?
I've tried with changing versions of all the librarys we use without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the displayed value in Chrome on Android wasn't changed until the blur event was triggered. So, I solved this by creating this small directive:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$on('blur', function(event, operation){
            if (operation == attrs.bluron) element[0].blur();
        });

    }
```